# Python Pandas get_close_matches lookup table problem

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the `get_close_matches` function which is working quite well. The problem is that I'm missing the relation to my lookup table within the result of that function. As the result table might contain more than one entry which is related to other data in my lookup table. Is the method not even returning any index or is there a different way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd

lookup_df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['rot', 'gelb', 'rote'],
                         'Name1': ['Peter', 'Hans', 'Gustav'],
                         'Name2': ['Pan', 'Wurst', 'Kraut']})
search_df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['rot', 'blau', 'gelb']})

# lookupDF = pd.read_excel('lookup.xlsx')
# searchDF = pd.read_excel('search.xlsx')

resultDF = search_df.copy(deep=True)

for (index, row) in search_df.iterrows():
   resultMatch = get_close_matches(row['Key'], lookupDF['Key'], n=10, cutoff=0.8)

  if resultMatch:
   resultDelta = 1 / len(resultMatch)
   addIndex = index

  for resultValue in resultMatch:
   # here I need to get the correspondent data of the lookup-table that is matching my resultValue
   lookupRow = lookupDF.loc[lookupDF['Key'] == resultValue]

   row['Matched Key'] = lookupRow['key']
   row['Matched Name 1'] = lookupRow['Name1']
   row['Matched Name 2'] = lookupRow['Name2']

   resultDF.loc[addIndex] = row
        addIndex = addIndex + resultDelta
```

But in this example I would always find the first matching in my lookup table (159, Peter, Pan) and I would never find (159, Gustav, Kraut).

[image]

Comment: Can ou please provide a reproducible example, including code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_close_matches()` function (from the [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) module) is primarily intended for string matching. **For numerical values**, a fuzzy matching algorithm is much easier to implement from scratch, because for each pair of values, you just need to check whether their difference is as small as desired.

Also note that in your loops, you are overwriting the values of `resultMatch` and `lookupRow` in each iteration. Instead, a typical Python pattern is to build up a list by extending it in each iteration, so that you have all the desired values in the end.

Here is an example using your data, slightly modified to show that the values do not have to match exactly:

```py
import pandas as pd

lookup_df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': [159.1, 5.2, 159.3],
                         'Name1': ['Peter', 'Hans', 'Gustav'],
                         'Name2': ['Pan', 'Wurst', 'Kraut']})
search_df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': [159, 58, 134]})

TOLERANCE = 0.8

keys = []
for searchkey in search_df.Key:
    keys.extend(lookup_df.query(
        "@searchkey - @TOLERANCE <= Key <= @searchkey + @TOLERANCE").Key.values)

print(lookup_df.query("Key in @keys"))
```

```
   Key    Name1   Name2
0  159.1  Peter   Pan
2  159.3  Gustav  Kraut
```

---

**If, however, the keys are strings,** you can use the difflib function like this:

```py
from difflib import get_close_matches
import pandas as pd

lookup_df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['hello', 'test', 'yello'],
                         'Name1': ['Peter', 'Hans', 'Gustav'],
                         'Name2': ['Pan', 'Wurst', 'Kraut']})
search_df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['bello', 'other', 'more']})

keys = []
for searchkey in search_df.Key:
    keys.extend(get_close_matches(searchkey, lookup_df.Key.values, n=10, cutoff=0.8))

print(lookup_df.query("Key in @keys"))
```

```
   Key    Name1   Name2
0  hello  Peter   Pan
2  yello  Gustav  Kraut
```

---

To combine the two tables, you could first replace the roughly matching key values in one of the tables with the exact key values from the other table and then merge the two tables:

```py
lookup_df['exact_key'] = lookup_df.Key
for searchkey in search_df.Key:
    for match in get_close_matches(searchkey, lookup_df.Key.values, n=10, cutoff=0.8):
        lookup_df.exact_key.replace(match, searchkey, inplace=True)

lookup_filtered = lookup_df.query("exact_key in @search_df.Key")
result = search_df.merge(lookup_filtered, how='outer', left_on='Key', right_on='exact_key')

print(result)
```

```
   Key_x Other  Key_y   Name1  Name2 exact_key
0  bello     a  hello   Peter    Pan     bello
1  bello     a  yello  Gustav  Kraut     bello
2  other     b    NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN
3   more     c    NaN     NaN    NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Sry my example was misleading, in my case the "key" is of type string. And you are right, the example is just simplified to highlight the main issue. In fact I'm storing the results in another DataFrame.

Comment: Okay, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly what I need. I extended the example to make it more clear. As I also need to modify the search table I also need to have a relation to it. Is that somehow possible to consider that in your example?

Comment: Made another edit to show how to combine the tables.